# Laravel 4.2 - Using entrust and confide

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, seeding

I am using ["zizaco/confide": "~4.0@dev"](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) and ["zizaco/entrust": "1.2.*@dev"](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust).

I have set everything up as described in the two tutorials(confide migrations). Furthermore, I have created the following models:

**User:**

```
<?php

use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser;
use Zizaco\Confide\Confide;
use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideEloquentRepository;
use Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends ConfideUser implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{
    use HasRole;

    /**
     * Get user by username
     * @param $username
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserByUsername( $username )
    {
        return $this->where('username', '=', $username)->first();
    }

    public function joined()
    {
        return String::date(Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-n-j G:i:s', $this->created_at));
    }

    public function saveRoles($inputRoles)
    {
        if(! empty($inputRoles)) {
            $this->roles()->sync($inputRoles);
        } else {
            $this->roles()->detach();
        }
    }

    public function currentRoleIds()
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        $roleIds = false;
        if( !empty( $roles ) ) {
            $roleIds = array();
            foreach( $roles as &$role )
            {
                $roleIds[] = $role->id;
            }
        }
        return $roleIds;
    }

    public static function checkAuthAndRedirect($redirect, $ifValid=false)
    {
        // Get the user information
        $user = Auth::user();
        $redirectTo = false;

        if(empty($user->id) && ! $ifValid) // Not logged in redirect, set session.
        {
            Session::put('loginRedirect', $redirect);
            $redirectTo = Redirect::to('user/login')
                ->with( 'notice', Lang::get('user/user.login_first') );
        }
        elseif(!empty($user->id) && $ifValid) // Valid user, we want to redirect.
        {
            $redirectTo = Redirect::to($redirect);
        }

        return array($user, $redirectTo);
    }

    public function currentUser()
    {
        return (new Confide(new ConfideEloquentRepository()))->user();
    }

    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

**Role:**

```
<?php

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

class Role extends EntrustRole {

    public function validateRoles( array $roles )
    {
        $user = Confide::user();
        $roleValidation = new stdClass();
        foreach( $roles as $role )
        {
            // Make sure theres a valid user, then check role.
            $roleValidation->$role = ( empty($user) ? false : $user->hasRole($role) );
        }
        return $roleValidation;
    }
}
```

**Permission:**

```
<?php

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustPermission;

class Permission extends EntrustPermission
{
    public function preparePermissionsForDisplay($permissions)
    {
        // Get all the available permissions
        $availablePermissions = $this->all()->toArray();

        foreach($permissions as &$permission) {
            array_walk($availablePermissions, function(&$value) use(&$permission){
                if($permission->name == $value['name']) {
                    $value['checked'] = true;
                }
            });
        }
        return $availablePermissions;
    }

    /**
     * Convert from input array to savable array.
     * @param $permissions
     * @return array
     */
    public function preparePermissionsForSave( $permissions )
    {
        $availablePermissions = $this->all()->toArray();
        $preparedPermissions = array();
        foreach( $permissions as $permission => $value )
        {
            // If checkbox is selected
            if( $value == '1' )
            {
                // If permission exists
                array_walk($availablePermissions, function(&$value) use($permission, &$preparedPermissions){
                    if($permission == (int)$value['id']) {
                        $preparedPermissions[] = $permission;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return $preparedPermissions;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I would like to seed my database in the beginning with values, therefore I created the follwing seeders:

**UserTableSeeder:**

```
<?php

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->delete();


        $users = array(
            array(
                'username'   => 'admin',
                'email'      => 'admin@example.org',
                'password'   => Hash::make('admin'),
                'confirmed'  => 1,
                'confirmation_code' => md5(microtime().Config::get('app.key')),
                'created_at' => new DateTime,
                'updated_at' => new DateTime,
            ),
            array(
                'username'   => 'moderator',
                'email'      => 'moderator@example.org',
                'password'   => Hash::make('moderator'),
                'confirmed'  => 1,
                'confirmation_code' => md5(microtime().Config::get('app.key')),
                'created_at' => new DateTime,
                'updated_at' => new DateTime,
            ),
            array(
                'username'   => 'user',
                'email'      => 'user@example.org',
                'password'   => Hash::make('user'),
                'confirmed'  => 1,
                'confirmation_code' => md5(microtime().Config::get('app.key')),
                'created_at' => new DateTime,
                'updated_at' => new DateTime,
            )
        );

        DB::table('users')->insert( $users );
    }

}
```

**RolesTableSeeder:**

```
<?php

class RolesTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('roles')->delete();

        $adminRole = new Role;
        $adminRole->name = 'adminRole';
        $adminRole->save();

        $standRole = new Role;
        $standRole->name = 'userRole';
        $standRole->save();

        $modRole = new Role;
        $modRole->name = 'modRole';
        $modRole->save();

        $user = User::where('username','=','admin')->first();
        $user->attachRole( $adminRole );

        $user = User::where('username','=','user')->first();
        $user->attachRole( $standRole );

        $user = User::where('username','=','moderator')->first();
        $user->attachRole( $modRole );

    }
}
```

**PermissionsTableSeeder:**

```
<?php

class PermissionsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('permissions')->delete();

        $permissions = array(
            array( // 1
                'name'         => 'manage_users',
                'display_name' => 'manage users'
            ),
            array( // 2
                'name'         => 'manage_roles',
                'display_name' => 'manage roles'
            ),
            array( // 3
                'name'         => 'standart_user_role',
                'display_name' => 'standart_user_role'
            ),
        );

        DB::table('permissions')->insert( $permissions );

        DB::table('permission_role')->delete();

        $role_id_admin = Role::where('name', '=', 'admin')->first()->id;
        $role_id_mod   = Role::where('name', '=', 'moderator')->first()->id;
        $role_id_stand = Role::where('name', '=', 'user')->first()->id;

        $permission_base = (int)DB::table('permissions')->first()->id - 1;

        $permissions = array(
            array(
                'role_id'       => $role_id_admin,
                'permission_id' => $permission_base + 1
            ),
            array(
                'role_id'       => $role_id_admin,
                'permission_id' => $permission_base + 2
            ),
            array(
                'role_id'       => $role_id_mod,
                'permission_id' => $permission_base + 1
            ),
            array(
                'role_id'       => $role_id_mod,
                'permission_id' => $permission_base + 3
            ),
            array(
                'role_id'       => $role_id_stand,
                'permission_id' => $permission_base + 3
            ),
        );

        DB::table('permission_role')->insert( $permissions );
    }

}
```

However, when running `db:seed`:

```
$ php artisan db:seed
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

Do you really wish to run this command? Y
Seeded: UsersTableSeeder
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","me
ssage":"Class User cannot extend from trait Zizaco\\Confide\\ConfideUser","file"
:"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel_project\\laravel-application\\app\\models\\User.php","line
":11}}
```

Any recommendations what I am doing wrong in my seeding?

I appreciate your answers!

**Update**

After changing the `UserModel` I get the following exception:

```
$ php artisan db:seed
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

Do you really wish to run this command? Y
Seeded: UsersTableSeeder
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","me
ssage":"Call to undefined method User::where()","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\larav
el_project\\laravel-application\\app\\database\\seeds\\RolesTableSeeder.php","line":21}
}
```

**Update 2**

When changing the user model to(as @MarcinNabiałek proposed):

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{
    use ConfideUser;
    use HasRole;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
$ php artisan db:seed
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

Do you really wish to run this command? Y
Seeded: UsersTableSeeder
Seeded: RolesTableSeeder



  [ErrorException]
  Trying to get property of non-object



db:seed [--class[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--force]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have clear message here - you cannot extend from Trait (message is clear enough I think: **Class User cannot extend from trait Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser**).

Instead of:

```
class User extends ConfideUser implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{
    use HasRole;
```

you should use:

```
class User implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{
    use ConfideUser;
    use HasRole;
```

**EDIT**

class `User` should obviously extend `Eloquent` (this is set be default) so it should be:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{
    use ConfideUser;
    use HasRole;
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! I changed the UserModel as you proposed. However, now I get an error in my RoleSeeder. I would appreciate your reply on this!

Comment: Thx I made the change to extend Eloquent. However, now I get the error of having user and roletable seeded however, permission table failed with: ` [ErrorException]
 Trying to get property of non-object` Any recommendations for that error?

Comment: @mrquad You need to ask another question showing exact error

Comment: I have added an update cause I think the following error is too tiny for another question. I would appreciate your thoughts on this!

Comment: This is probably because of `PermissionsTableSeeder` or `Role` but you should check it yourself and ask new question if this seeder causes problem